# Try Now button is not showing on published play store application having Instant app feature enabled

Tags: android, google-play, android-instant-apps

I have updated my current play store app with the Instant app feature enabled.
But it is still not showing the "Try Now" button after waited for 5 days.

I have implemented an instant app feature in a current app and updated it like below:

1. added a dependency in app-level Gradle:
   implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:17.0.0"
2. To enable instant app right-click on app module -> Refactor -> Enable instant app support.
3. Increment a version code to 1 and uploaded a new build on the play store.

Could you guys please help me out to find out the missing element or a direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same question.

You may need setup to show the list box at the Setup > Advanced settings
(This image is already added)
[image: setup]

And try to changing the list box in the upper right corner of the screen to "Instant apps only"
[image: console image]

Comment: Hey @kyane, Thanks for the reply.
But I have already uploaded my application in production.
There is nothing in testing.

Comment: Yes. That's right.
You need to upload two versions, one normal(Standard) and one "try now"(Instant apps only) version.You can use the same aab file.

Comment: Hi @kyane, thanks for the detailed info.
I have performed the same steps that you mentioned but it didn't allow me to upload apk with the same version in the Instant app type.

Comment: You can choose an apk from library instead of uploading. But I'm not sure .apk is allowed. The .aab is fine.

Comment: Hey @kyane,
After uploading an apk with a different version code as an Instant app, it shows the following error on the play store.
"Some files you've uploaded aren't instant-enabled. "
Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: check your manifest including `<dist:module dist:instant="true" />`.  It should be automatically enabled when you run "Enable instant app support".

Comment: Yes. I did the same.

Answer (score 0):

Heyy, Kutbi

Thanks to @kyane, He has explained a lot.

First to make an instant app, make a copy of your project and [Follow](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle) the the steps given by the Google to apply for instant apps.

And you can apply for aab bundel for instant app also.

Comment: Yes. I accepted kyane answer.
It worked and now shows the "try now" button on the play store.
One thing is I have to upload the .aab file for both the mode. (Install and Instant).
Still don't know why .apk didn't accept.